# Error "No instance for (Num [t])" in Collatz function

Tags: haskell, list, collatz

I am new to Haskell, and programming in general. I am trying to define a function which generates the sequence of Collatz numbers from *n*. I have:

```
collatz n = (collatz' n) : 1
   where collatz' n = (takeWhile (>1) (collatz'' n))
          where collatz'' n = n : collatz'' (collatz''' n)
                 where collatz''' 1 = 1
                       collatz''' n = if (even n) then (div n 2) else ((3*2)+1)
```

When I run this in GHCi, I get the error:

```
No instance for (Num [t])
  arising from the literal `2' at <interactive>:1:7
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t])
```

I don't know what this means. The problem seems to be appending "1" to the list. This problem emerges because

```
collatz' n = (takeWhile (>0) (collatz'' n))
```

generates an infinite sequence of "1"s following the correct Collatz sequence; however,

```
collatz' n = (takeWhile (>1) (collatz'' n))
```

generates all Collatz numbers from *n* except "1". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ony's answer is correct, but since you're new to Haskell, maybe this is a clearer explanation.  The `:` operator *pre*pends a value to a list, so doing `somelist : 7` is invalid since that's trying to *ap*pend a value to a list.  That's why `(collatz' n) : 1` doesn't compile, since the type of `(collatz' n)` is a list of numbers.

Try replacing the `: 1` with `++ [1]`.

Comment: `(collatz' n) : []` is fine. It will produce something like `[[a]]` (actually original example is compiled, but there is no type bind for first argument `a` that can satisfy class restrictions: `collatz :: (Integral a, Num [[a]]) => a -> [[a]]`). Problem is that any numbers (i.e. `1`) can be compiled only into value of data which satisfies class `Num a`.

Comment: Thanks also: I've rewritten whole functions before in order to force (:) to work. You just saved me lots of time!

Answer (score 6):

`(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`
Your first line `collatz n = (collatz' n) : 1` forces `1` to become `[a]`.
I guess you wanted something like `(collatz' n) ++ [1]`
And you have error in `if (even n) then (div n 2) else ((3*2)+1)` there should be `((3*n)+1` or something like that else you have `collatz''' 7 = 7`

Comment: Thank you: that makes sense, and clarifies (:) for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go at the problem may be for you to use a Data.Sequence structure instead of a list. Sequences allow you to "snoc" a value (put a value on the back of a sequence) as well as the more usual "cons" (put it on the front of the sequence).

Another solution for you may be to use `span` to make your own "takeUntil" function.

Let me explain: `span p xs` gives you the same answer as `(takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)` for whichever `p` function and `xs` list you'd use, the same way that `splitAt n xs` is the same as `(take n xs, drop n xs)`.

Anyway, you can use `span` to make your own "takeUntil" function:

```
takeUntil p xs = taken ++ take 1 dropped where
                 (taken, dropped) = span p xs
```

This is the form that you were looking for, when you used the `collatz n = (collatz' n) : 1` form.

I hope this helps.